# Typo when calling subref dies with `Not a GLOB reference`

Tags: perl, syntax, glob

A coworker's typo when calling a subref raised this strange syntax question. If I call a subref without the dereference arrow, perl dies with `Not a GLOB reference`. However, if the subref is called as a method on a blessed object, it runs fine.

What does this have to do with globs? And why does the method call work?

```
use 5.12.0;
use Try::Tiny;

my $f = sub { 'sub ref' };
my $obj = bless({}, 'Blessed');

try {
   say $f($obj); # should be $f->();
} catch { 
   say "ERROR: $_";
};

say $obj->$f();
```

Output:

```
C:\code>perl dispatch.pl
ERROR: Not a GLOB reference at dispatch.pl line 8.

sub ref
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`say`, like `print`, accepts an optional filehandle/typeglob to direct output to, eg:

```
my $f = \*STDERR;
say $f ("This goes to stderr.");
```

I didn't realize until now that you could do a method call on a subroutine reference, but sure enough, the `perlobj` man page states:

> If the right side of the arrow is a scalar containing a reference to a
>        subroutine, then this is equivalent to calling the referenced subroutine
>        directly with the class name or object on the left side of the arrow as its
>        first argument. No lookup is done and there is no requirement that the
>        subroutine be defined in any package related to the class name or object on the
>        left side of the arrow.